# Can not display submodule vector in omnetpp

Tags: module, omnet++

I stuck with this problem. I can't display submodules vector in design mode on omnetpp++ with this code:

```
simple Txc10
{
    parameters:
        @display("i=block/routing");
    gates:
        input in[];  // declare in[] and out[] to be vector gates
        output out[];
}

network Tictoc10
{
    submodules:
        tic[6]: Txc10;
    connections:
        tic[0].out++ --> {  delay = 100ms; } --> tic[1].in++;
        tic[0].in++ <-- {  delay = 100ms; } <-- tic[1].out++;

        tic[1].out++ --> {  delay = 100ms; } --> tic[2].in++;
        tic[1].in++ <-- {  delay = 100ms; } <-- tic[2].out++;

        tic[1].out++ --> {  delay = 100ms; } --> tic[4].in++;
        tic[1].in++ <-- {  delay = 100ms; } <-- tic[4].out++;

        tic[3].out++ --> {  delay = 100ms; } --> tic[4].in++;
        tic[3].in++ <-- {  delay = 100ms; } <-- tic[4].out++;

        tic[4].out++ --> {  delay = 100ms; } --> tic[5].in++;
        tic[4].in++ <-- {  delay = 100ms; } <-- tic[5].out++;
}
```

This is a result of above code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cw4on.png)

How do i display submodules like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2O8p.png)

Please help me, Tks everybody

Answer (score 0):

The presented code is correct. After starting the simulation submodules will be placed in different positions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a matrix layout for a module vector like this:

```
host[20]: Host {
    @display("p=,,m,4,50,50");
}
```

For more details, you can read this document https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:graphics:submodule-positioning